# Связка Nginx и Kestrel - где использовать https?

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel

Есть веб-приложение на .NET Core. По умолчанию в нем используется Kestrel, имеющий всю необходимую для работы приложения базовую функциональность, в пом числе использование https. Но сам MS советует использовать другие веб-серверы (IIS, Apache, Nginx) для расширения возможностей взаимодействия с веб-службами, в т.ч. в качестве reverse proxy.
В связи с чем возник такой вопрос - необходимо ли включать поддержку https в Kestrel, или же достаточно будет включить ее в Nginx и передавать запросы на Kestrel по http?
Примерный конфиг Nginx в рамках данного вопроса:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass          http://kestrel;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;

    }
}
```

Comment: Достаточно включить HTTPS на Nginx. HTTPS для "внутреннего" использования нужен только из соображений безопасности. Если нет угроз в интранете, то HTTPS между проксей и сервером приложений не обязателен. Угрозы такие: прослушивание TCP трафика и MITM-атаки.

Comment: @TotalPusher стоит оформить ответом :)

Comment: @DmitryMalikov стоит поставить галку на ответе ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работоспособности достаточно включить HTTPS на Nginx.

HTTPS между реверс-прокси и сервером приложений не обязателен, но его следует использовать из соображений безопасности. Угрозы такие:

- прослушивание TCP трафика
- MITM-атаки

Если таких угроз нет, HTTPS между Nginx и Kestrel как таковой не нужен. Сюда можно отнести такие частные случаи:

- оба демона находятся на одном сервере, доступ к серверу только у доверенных
- трафик ходит внутри DMZ

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что для варианта nginx+kestrel на одном хосте можно не только заменять https на http (это снижает нагрузку на процессор), но и делать общение не по протоколу http 1.1 а по http 1.0 или отключать чанки - это конечно уже совсем копейки производительности, но иногда хочется побольше выжать ;)

Comment: @AK nginx и kestrel в разных docker-контейнерах, а как они будут развертываться на реальной инфраструктуре, я не знаю. Но очевидно, что доступ снаружи к kestrel не будет, только через прокси.

Comment: Про работоспособность я не сомневался, все уже работает. Однако раньше я и на kestrel поднимал https, но сейчас задумался - зачем? Из плюсов - гораздо меньше плясок с сертификатами при разработке. Из минусов - вот эти вопросы безопасности, если переносить приложение "как есть" из дев-ветки без включения https.